# Bluetooth and laptop speakers working at the same time

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I installed eOS on an `HP Envy x360 Convertible 13-y0xx`. Bluetooth is doing something strange. If I'm connected to my Bluetooth headsets, open YouTube through Epiphany, everything sounds normal. But if I open YouTube through Firefox it plays the audio through the laptop speakers.

Here's where it gets crazy. I can play an MP3 song through eOS's music player at the same time I'm playing a video on YouTube through Firefox and I can hear both Bluetooth audio AND the laptop's audio playing at the same time. They're both active.

After fiddling around with the settings and installing Blueman, I got this notification. I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

[image: Notification of Bluetooth connected via serial port]

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install PulseAudio volume control from the app center and then change the profile in configuration and the output device

Answer (score 0):

Go to sound settings and choose the appropriate output device.